# React Native Firebase: How can you display a text from Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

i am trying to make an app with React native, Firebase and Expo that shows a text that is loaded from the Firestore.

For example: I want the app to display "helloworld". So my Firebase backend looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89lAo.png)

But i dont know how to load the text from Firestore into the app and how to display it.

It would be great if you could help me out.

Thanks

Comment: This is a third party. I have used it and it worked well. It is officially recommended by react native or firebase (sorry I forgot). https://rnfirebase.io/

Comment: Between https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data, you should be able to get started. If you're having trouble making it work, edit your question to [show what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add library 'react-native-firebase'

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
```

Then get the data from firestore using below function

```
getDataFromFirebase(){
firebase.firestore().collection('testcollections').doc(testdoc).get()
     .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log("Document data: ", doc.data().testfield);
        }else{
          console.log("Document data is not empty: ");
        }
      })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('firebase Error::'+error)
     })
}
```